# Is it ethical to edit a question to get more views?

Tags: discussion, edits

I've added a bounty to one of my questions, but it's barely done anything to attract other users. I'm pretty sure more people viewed the question when I first posted it than have viewed it since I've added the bounty.

Since the bounty doesn't seem to be doing it's job, would it be fine to make edits to the question to "bump it up"? It seems that the most recently changed questions hit the front page, rather than the most recent bounties.

Comment: I'd wait a bit on the bounty. Questions with bounties closer to expiration tend to see huge view traffic and votes lately, from what I've seen. I bet you'll experience that.

Comment: [Your bountied question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33505646/loading-dependencies-outside-of-project-directory-in-the-intern) still has 4 days on the bounty.  Just wait it out.

Comment: I would not edit the question unless you need to, if the question doesn't need to be edited then don't. You can clean some things up as an edit, and I don't think these is anything wrong with that, but otherwise I wouldn't recommend trying to misuse the system.